# Looping in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am tring to loop loop a jQuery command 5 times. Here is my code:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $("#droppable_"+i).droppable({
       activeClass: 'ui-state-hover',
       hoverClass: 'ui-state-active',
       drop: function(event, ui) {
          $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight').find('p').html('Dropped!');
       }
    });
 }
```

For some reason I can't get it to work. Can someone help me please?

Comment: why are you defining a droppable element inside a cycle? It seems to be useless

Comment: Why are you looping, incrementing i each time, and then never using i?

Comment: The OP's code has since been updated. The i is being used now to increment the IDs. See my answer (and link) for an example of what I assume the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your updated code works fine. Remember that you also need to set something as draggable.

Working example (using your loop) is http://jsfiddle.net/t56TE/

```
$("#draggable").draggable(); 
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $("#droppable_"+i).droppable({
       activeClass: 'ui-state-hover',
       hoverClass: 'ui-state-active',
       drop: function(event, ui) {
          $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight').find('p').html('Dropped!');
       }
    });
} ​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable_1" class="ui-widget-header">
    <p>Drop here</p>
</div>
<div id="droppable_2" class="ui-widget-header">
    <p>Drop here</p>
</div>
<div id="droppable_3" class="ui-widget-header">
    <p>Drop here</p>
</div>
<div id="droppable_4" class="ui-widget-header">
    <p>Drop here</p>
</div>​
```

Comment: +1 but please post the solution code in your answer in addition to the link. :o)

Comment: Code added. Although it's the OP's code (other than the `draggable` line).

Comment: Yes, it's just that if the link every breaks, your answer will make more sense to future readers if the code is there.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments pointed out, you're not really doing anything useful in your loop. (There will only ever be one "droppable" item because you are using an ID.)

However, what I **think** you're going for is you want to do all that stuff to each item found by your selector. You could do something like this:

```
$('.select').each(function() {
  // Do your stuff here.
});
```

You should read up more on the [each function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to understand how it works.

Comment: Whoa...two downvotes? Anybody care to explain why? My response was valid at the time he originally asked his question.

Comment: Sorry, if you update your answer in line with the current question I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: @Blair - Eh, it's okay. Not really worth it since your answer is spot on. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have 5 elements that you're trying to apply `droppable` to, each element with its own unique id.

Maybe you could put an **isDroppable** class on each element and then you don't need to loop your jQuery code, just do this:

```
$(".isDroppable").each( function(i,elem) {
    $(elem).droppable({
        activeClass: 'ui-state-hover',
        hoverClass: 'ui-state-active',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight').find('p').html('Dropped!');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't know JQuery can apply a function to a set of elements !

```
$('*[id^=droppable]').droppable({
       activeClass: 'ui-state-hover',
       hoverClass: 'ui-state-active',
       drop: function(event, ui) {
          $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight').find('p').html('Dropped!');
       }
    });
```

(The selector would be more effective with a class)

Comment: Does *this* inside the drop function refer back to the correct object?

Answer (score 0):

**Why don't you just put all the ID's inside the selector?**

I guess a loop would be ok if you plan to extend this further, but for now I would just stick with this:

```
$("#droppable_1, #droppable_2, #droppable_3, #droppable_4, #droppable_5").droppable({
   activeClass: 'ui-state-hover',
   hoverClass: 'ui-state-active',
   drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight').find('p').html('Dropped!');
   }
});
```